# Display wordpress version on external website

Tags: wordpress

I have multiple WP websites and one main website.

I would like to use the main website to show the date of the last update.

I am open to jQuery / PHP code, widgets, plugins or anything else that might work.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably loads of ways to do this, depending on what access you have to the sites.

- If you haven't disabled it then you can fetch the homepage from each site using curl or wget and pull out the

  ```
  <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.9.1" />
  ```

  tag.
- If you have filesystem access (i.e. on the same machine) then you can look at wp-includes/version.php and find the

  ```
  $wp_version = '3.9.1';
  ```

  line, either by grep or by (riskier!) including the file. You can even get this over SSH from remote machines with the right keys etc. set up.

I expect it's in the database too if you have direct database access to the other sites, but I can't see it at first glance: only a numeric `db_version` in `wp_options`.

---

I realise now that's the version, your question title, not the update date, your question body.

As far as I can see the date isn't anywhere obvious, but the last-checked-for-updates date is available from `get_site_transient('update_core')` (or `update_plugins` or `update_themes`) in the last_checked field. If you want to read these direct from the database then they're `SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name LIKE '_site_transient_update_%';`.

Comment: I just noticed that I wasn't consistent - my fault. I meant the date although I could make the version work too if it was easier. 

I have a place clients can sign in to see information about their account. I wanted to include something like "It has been 1 year since your last update".

I have full admin access to every site that I would need this information from.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where the update-date is recorded, sorry, or any easy points to hook into in update-core.php with a 'record-last-update-time' plugin either. I suspect a small code change to capture this is the way to go (you can then e.g. either save it in the database or hit a web service on your master site to record the upgrade) but I don't know the best way to make that change sorry. You mentined jQuery: you could even add some script to the admin UI through a plugin that traps clicks on the upgrade button and then makes an Ajax post to record it, but that's not a great way IMO.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here there's always the [WordPress-specific StackExchange site](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) where someone might know better.